# Spring boot Request Mapping with Schedule

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, schedule

I'm newbie on spring boot. I'm already implement some request mappings with successfully output in json.

`localhost:8080/gJson`

```
 {
    ad: "Windows 10",
    mimari: "amd64",
    versiyon: "10.0",
    diskSize: 918,
    freediskSize: 614,
    cores: 8,
    usablediskSize: 614
    }
```

And My Controller here

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Controller      
public class GreetingController {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/gJson", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public @ResponseBody  MyPojo gJson(){
         ...
     }
}
```

And now, I need ... example when I'm going to this link > `localhost:8080/GetInfo`     getting json from `localhost:8080/gJson` but every "X" seconds.

Thanks For Helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is /GetInfo being served? Is it just a standard HTML page? If so you can code a Javascript element that has a [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to make an [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to the `/gJson` endpoint. There are a number of other ways to do it depending on what libraries you want to use to have browser to server communications.

*** Update ***
Sample project: https://github.com/ShawnTuatara/stackoverflow-38890600

Main aspect that allows the refresh is the HTML page at `src/main/resources/static/GetInfo.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>GetInfo</title>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        window.setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : "/gJson"
            }).done(function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                $("body").text(jqXHR.responseText);
            });
        }, 10000);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

The controller is straightforward as outlined in the question.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/gJson", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public MyPojo gJson() {
        return new MyPojo("Windows 10", System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

Finally the MyPojo is just a simple two field class.

```
public class MyPojo {
    private String ad;
    private long timestamp;

    public MyPojo(String ad, long timestamp) {
        this.ad = ad;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getAd() {
        return ad;
    }

    public void setAd(String ad) {
        this.ad = ad;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

I included the timestamp so that you can see the time refreshing every 10 seconds on the web page.

Comment: ye i Have getInfo.html.. You mean call ajax setInterval right?

Comment: window.setInterval() ... the answer has a link to a page that has Javascript examples.

Comment: Firstly, I apologize for my bad English.I know setInverval() but spring boot requestmapping just working 1time.. And i think You mean call 'localhost:8080/gJson' i ajax every 10 second.But I need gJson page loading every 10 seconds from Spring boot with Request Mapping.

Comment: Can you update your original question with the html code for the GetInfo page?

Comment: My GetInfo page is blank page now.Why you need GetInfo page? I'm ask because i need using schedule with request mapping from spring boot.I know ' setInterval(function () {
  $.ajax({
url:"http://localhost:8080/gJson"
.....
});

    },10000);

Comment: I guess I am not understanding exactly what you are wanting. The controller itself can't have a schedule to it. The client has to initiate the request and set a timer as to how often it would like to query the `/gJson` endpoint. Can you try and re-state what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want just "Request maping" is refreshing every 10 second without user request. For example, users found the bet for results and "10" returned. Before making the request User 2 "Apache Tomcat" automatically restart "request" ever did, and the result was variable 15. and then I found the user had bet ( 'Ajax SetInterval' part) and I want to see as a result of 15. I can not explain my problem could duly. But still in Thanks for your interest.

Comment: it occurs when the user wants each page again. Problem solved. Thank you